# eval-expression on (setq helm-debug t) does not change describe-variable output

Tags: helm, debugging, variables, help, eval-expression

I'm running this version of Emacs:

```
GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.11) of 2019-09-23, modified by Debian
```

Installed on Ubuntu 19.10 via apt, and not built from source.

I'm trying to set the `helm-debug` variable so that I can see what Helm is doing to debug a problem (`helm-locate` is not showing files that exist in a directory whose parent element has `.git` in it).

So in the past, I could use `M-:` (mapped to `eval-expression`) and type in an expression, which I did with this:

```
(progn (setq helm-debug 'xxx) (message "helm-debug == %S" helm-debug))
```

And I get what I expect to see in the message area of:

```
"helm-debug == xxx"
```

And, I go back in and run `M-:` again to check on the value like this:

```
helm-debug
```

I see `xxx` as the resulting value.  All good so far.

But then, when I type `C-h v` (mapped to `describe-variable`), and then type in `helm-debug`, and I see this:

```
helm-debug is a variable defined in ‘helm.el’.
Its value is nil

Documentation:
If non-‘nil’, write log message to ‘helm-debug-buffer’.
Default is ‘nil’, which disables writing log messages because the
size of ‘helm-debug-buffer’ grows quickly.
```

Why is it reporting `nil`, when I have clearly set it inside the `eval-expression` call?

For reference, the `defvar` for this variable resides in `~/.emacs.d/elpa/helm-core-20191013.626/helm.el` in my setup (meaning Helm mode has been recently upgraded)

```
(defvar helm-debug nil
  "If non-`nil', write log message to `helm-debug-buffer'.
Default is `nil', which disables writing log messages because the
size of `helm-debug-buffer' grows quickly.")
```

Comment: Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q`? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: I refrained from bisecting the init file because this seemed to be deep in the guts of helm mode itself.  And xuchunyang's answer at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/53370/15483 confirms that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's intended:

```
helm-internal calls 
  helm-log-save-maybe calls 
    (setq helm-debug nil)
```

thus whenever a helm session ends, `helm-debug` will be reset to nil. I guess it's because the log buffer can grow too quickly.

Instead of changing `helm-debug` directly, according to helm's own help (you can get it by type `C-h m` within any helm session, I have pasted the related section below), you can use `C-h C-d`:

> #### Debugging Helm
>
> Helm exposes the special variable `helm-debug`: setting it to non-nil
>   will enable Helm logging in a special outline-mode buffer. **Helm resets**
>   **the variable to nil at the end of each session**.
>
> For convenience, C-h C-d allows you to turn on debugging for this
>   session only. To avoid accumulating log entries while you are typing
>   patterns, you can use C-! to turn off updating.  When you are ready
>   turn it on again to resume logging.
>
> Once you exit your Helm session you can access the debug buffer with
>   `helm-debug-open-last-log`.  It is possible to save logs to dated
>   files when `helm-debug-root-directory` is set to a valid directory.
>
> Note: Be aware that Helm log buffers grow really fast, so use
>   `helm-debug` only when needed.